# How to loop and make array object in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I want to make array object like this:

```
{'book1':3, 'book2':4, 'book3':5}
```

from an array like this

```
['book1', 'book1', 'book1', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 
'book2', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3']
```

How to do that? my idea is looping, but dont know to count the same value

*sorry for bad explanation

Comment: In Python that first data structure is called a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Looping is certainly a valid way to accomplish what you want to do. I'd suggest reading up on dictionaries, trying it out, and updating this with your code if you have a specific question or problem. Note that it's not necessary but using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can provide a concise solution.

Answer (score 2):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a handy builtin for this exact task:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['book1', 'book1', 'book1', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3']
print(dict(Counter(lst)))
```

Output:

```
{'book1': 3, 'book2': 4, 'book3': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
arr = ['book1', 'book1', 'book1', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3']

final = {}

# loop through each item in the array
# if it is NOT found in the dictionary, put it
# in the dictionary and give it a count of 1
# if it IS found in the dictionary, increment its value
for x in arr:
    if x in final:
        final[x] += 1
    else:
        final[x] = 1

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is made for exactly such thing.

```
from collections import Counter

li =['book1', 'book1', 'book1', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book2', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3', 'book3']
print(dict(Counter(li)))
#{'book1': 3, 'book2': 4, 'book3': 5}
```